How to iterate the array inside array of object in react js?
I am trying to iterate the data but it saying testData is not iterable.
This is my code  -
const testData = details?.[0]?.one?.map((item) => {
    const labelTwo =
      item?.itemType === 'FIRST' ? 'newLabel' : 'oldLabel';
    return {
      label: details?.[0]?.one?.length > 1 ? labelTwo : 'labelOne',
      value: item?.value,
    };
  });
  const myData: Item[] = [
    ...testData,
    {
      label: 'first',
      value: 'firstValue',
    },
    isVisible && {
      label: 'second',
      value: 'secondValue',
    },
  ];
return (
  <>
    {myData?.map((item: Item) => {
      return (
       <div>
        <div>{item?.label}</div>
        <div>{item?.value}</div>
       </div>
      );
    }
  </>
)

Below in return when I am trying to iterate myData using map function then it is saying testData is not iterable.
Am I doing anything wrong ? what will be the best approach here to iterate the data

maybe it is undefined when doing the ...testData.
have you logged it before the myData line to see. if it is expected to be undefined have a fallback like (details?.[0]?.one || []).map...

@cmgchess I am doing the null and undefined check using ? operator.

but even with the check you still end up with testData = undefined. your code until that wont break. but when you are trying to spread the undefined it breaks

As @cmgchess mentioned, the error "testData is not iterable" happens because you are trying to spread an object that is not iterable.
Looking at your code, the most likely cause is that testData is undefined.
Try this:
const testData = details?.[0]?.one?.map((item) => {
  const labelTwo = item?.itemType === 'FIRST' ? 'newLabel' : 'oldLabel';
  return {
    label: details?.[0]?.one?.length > 1 ? labelTwo : 'labelOne',
    value: item?.value,
  };
}) || []; // Default to empty array if undefined


There is possibility that undefined could be the value of testData so rewrite something like this would handle the undefined scenario
const myData: Item[] = [
    ...(testData ?? []),
    {
      label: 'first',
      value: 'firstValue',
    },
    isVisible && {
      label: 'second',
      value: 'secondValue',
    },
  ];


There are a few things to correct:

Conditional Object in array
It seems you’re trying to insert an object when isVisible is true in myData . To achieve this, you should use the following syntax: ...(isVisable ? [{ label: 'second', value: 'secondValue' }] : [])
Syntax error in jsx
The myData?.map function’s return block is missing a closing parenthesis for the map callback. Add ) to properly close the map callback

The corrected code for myData would look like this:
const myData: Item[] = [
  ...testData,
  {
    label: 'first',
    value: 'firstValue',
  },
  ...(isVisible ? [{ label: 'second', value: 'secondValue' }] : []),
];

And the return block:
return (
  <>
    {myData?.map((item: Item) => (
      <div>
        <div>{item?.label}</div>
        <div>{item?.value}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
);


You should try doing this if you want to avoid the error and if the testData is really optional.
const myData = [
...(testData.length > 0 ? testData : []),
  {
    label: 'first',
    value: 'firstValue',
  },
  ...(isVisible ? [{ label: 'second', value: 'secondValue' }] : []),
];

